# Regex - Find Last Occurence in String (\s Space Character)

Tags: php, regex

I want to match and replace some characters of a string (phone number) with regex.

For example:

```
(525) 525 52 25
```

Replace to:

```
525 525 5225
```

Replaced Characters:

> ()" " //<-- Without " characters, last \s whitespace between 52 25

What should i do?

I'v tried:

```
/[\(\)\s]/g
```

Matched () and all space characters.

Comment: @georg php (you can see in the tags)

Comment: Yes, but your RE is javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below code which removes  `(` or `)` symbols and the space which was before the last two digits,

```
<?php
$mystring = "(525) 525 52 25";
echo preg_replace('~[()]| (?=\d{2}$)~', '', $mystring);
?>
```

Output:

```
525 525 5225
```

**OR**

```
<?php
$mystring = "(525) 525 52 25";
echo preg_replace('~[()]| (?=\S*$)~', '', $mystring);
?>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qE6oS6/11)

**Explanation:**

- `[()]` Matches `(` or `)` symbols.
- `|` Logical OR operator is usually used to combine two regexes.
- `<space>(?=\S*$)` Matches the Space(ie, last space) which was followed by zero or more non-space characters and the line end.
- At-last all the matched characters are replaced with an empty string.

Comment: It is not working in here (maybe works with php i will try)
http://www.regexr.com/39bo4

Comment: regexr.com is specilly designed for javascript.

Comment: Okay i'm trying with php now wait a sec please :)

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan in javascript `"(525) 525 52 25".replace(/[()]| (?=\S*$)/g, '');`

Comment: Thank you :) nicely done! By the way if you write the explanation that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo preg_replace('/[()]|\s(?=\S+$)/', '', '(525) 525 52 25');
```